# Oracle: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

My query pulls two strings - no numeric types at all, yet the Oracle client gives me the exception above.  Any ideas?

Here is the query - all fields are strings:

```
 SELECT project_name 
        , project_title
        , project_name as Job2   
        , project_name as Job1  
 FROM PROJ
```

Here is the exception:

```
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.FirstResult()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
   at Partners.Core.Data.Database.FillDataSet(DataSet& dataSet, IDbCommand command, String[] tableNames) in c:\Dropbox\svn\partners\libraries\internal\Partners.Core\Data\Database.cs:line 999
```

Comment: There's no exception here.

Comment: Could be.. If you give us more information..

Comment: Why aren't you using the Oracle dB Provider? I bet it wouldn't happen if you switch ODP.NET or even try OleDb to prove the root cause quickly

Comment: Why do you select PROJ.project_name three times in the first place?

Comment: The results are aliased to different fields in the query.  sometimes they have different names, but in this case they do not.

Answer (score 6):

Shoot now I recall that I have seen this before.  The Oracle client is 32-bit only.  And so my .NET app needs to be x86 compiled.  So annoying!  And the message is so deceptive.

Comment: Your solution worked for a similar issue. I was getting this error on IIS 8 where the app pool did not allow 32 bit applications. Some I set that property to true, the error went away. Thanks!

Comment: Just to add a little more information: if you are deploying to a server with IIS 8, and Sharepoint 2013, the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" flag **won't** work by default, and will instead crash your application. [This article](http://manasbhardwaj.net/running-32-bit-web-application-iis-8/) has a fully working solution. (I came across this problem with our IBM System i at work, and the IBM driver for it.)

Answer (score 5):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariae/archive/2012/07/05/quot-arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow-quot-error-running-a-report-that-uses-a-connection-data-source-to-oracle-10.aspx

bug in the Oracle ODBC driver.  It affects the versions: 10.2.0.4 to 11.2.0.1 of Oracle and only the 64 bit driver (not the 32 bit driver).

Edit (Jan 2022): link from MSDN went dead. Here's a link to the Oracle page: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1181253_1.html