# Convert Number without leading zero for using in C#

Tags: c#, database, oracle, numbers, converters

I have a Oracle-view which gives me those data:

```
DATUM              STUNDE LAUFZEIT
-------------- ---------- -----------
30.10.14 00:00         11  ,433333333
```

The column `LAUFZEIT` is declared as `NUMBER`. Which format to I need to convert the column to get `0,433333333` or rounded to `0,4`?

[image]

I already tried some types like `Convert.ToSingle(reader.GetValue(2))` but always get a error like

> System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Thanks!

Comment: The problem there could be related to , and . .  Because c# uses . instead of , for differentating between before and after comma.  Can you try to convert the reader.GetValue(2).ToString().Replace(",", ".") if that solves your error?

Comment: What number are you working with? [From the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faab9yks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), "value represents a number that is less than Single.MinValue or greater than Single.MaxValue. " It [works for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GeAM50)

Comment: You could try using `Convert.ToDouble` and then to display it as the 0.4 you could cut it off by using `String.Format("{0:0,0}",Number)` where `number` is the double variable

Comment: Do you need that in sql or in C#? Have you tried [ROUND(LAUFZEIT, 1)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm)?

Comment: What version of Oracle do you use? If it is 10.2.0.4 to 11.2.0.1, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16319485/335858) may be related.

Comment: If its a number a simple reader.GetFloat(2) should do. A missing leading zero is only a problem when working with strings and it does not seem like you need strings somewhere.

Comment: @Thomas `reader.GetValue(2).ToString().Replace(",", ".")` thanks but doesn't work

Comment: @Sayse thanks but doesn't work for me because of the `,` I think. `Datatype` is only shown as `NUMBER` in the Oracle SQL Developer, no more info about the `NUMBER`

Comment: @maam27 I already tried `Convert.ToDouble` and gives me the same OverflowException

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I use 11.2.0.2.0 so this should be fixed. thanks

Comment: @Ralf Tried `reader.GetFloat(2)` but get the exception `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetFloat(Int32 i)`

Comment: Then i doubt your LAUFZEIT column is of type number.

Comment: @Ralf I added a screenshot to my post, the other columns are not relevant

Comment: As @TimSchmelter already said and as it stays for instance [here](http://www.itjungles.com/fixed-oci-22053-overflow-error.html) 
you should round your data `round(laufzeit, 4)`. I checked it for query `select 1/3 as test from dual` which produced OverflowException in C#, after rounding it worked fine.

Comment: @PonderStibbons I rounded the values in my view and now it's working fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always add a leading zero yourself before parsing. Adding a zero to the start of a number will NEVER change it.

`Convert.ToSingle('0' + reader.GetString(2).Replace(',','.'))` should do it.

I advice to use reader.GetString() before parsing.

Also it would be better to do:

```
Single a ;
if(Single.TryParse('0' + reader.GetString(2).Replace(',','.')), out a))
{
    //Success code here
}
else
{
    //Code to execute if string was not parsable here
}
```

In this way you won't get an exception

Comment: Tried `Convert.ToSingle('0' + reader.GetString(2))` but get the error >System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetString(Int32 i) at Tool.Auswertung.btn_start_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: You're right, it goes wrong because of the comma, it wants a point as a decimal seperator, Dmitry Bychenko's answer should do it and if not, try combining the two solutions.

Comment: @NilsO or a tostring in combination with replace in combination with your answer (as he is always getting a , for decimal a replace is imho as valid as using culture)

Comment: A replace is the better option if you're not sure whether your decimal seperator will be a comma or a point imho, but you're correct a replace will also work and I edited my answer to account for it.

Comment: @NilsO I come not so far, by trying `string test = reader.GetString(2);` I get the exception `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)`

Comment: hmmmmm is it sure that all values are set (thus that there  are no null values for that field?)

Comment: Try `if(!reader.IsDBNull(2)) string test = reader.GetString(2);`

Answer (score 2):

You have to mention a currect *Culture*:

```
  Object source = ",433333333";

  // This will fail with exception - Neutral Culture uses decimal point, not comma
  //Single single = Convert.ToSingle(source, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  // OK: Russian culture (ru-RU) uses decimal comma, not decimal point
  Single single = Convert.ToSingle(source, new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

To represent the value in desired form, use *formatting*, e.g. for *0,4*:

```
  // F1 - one floating point
  // "ru-RU" for decimal comma
  String result = single.ToString("F1", new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

Edit: having seen on the *Exception stack trace*, i.e.

`Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.DecimalConv.GetDecimal(IntPtr numCtx)`

one can conclude that the problem is in the

```
`Oracle.DataAccess.Types.DecimalConv.GetDecimal`
```

the origin of the error may be in the fact that Oracle `Number(36)` or the the like is bigger that .Net `Decimal`. Since you can't change `Oracle.DataAccess` library you can convert to String just in the query:

```
  select ...
         cast(LAUFZEIT as VarChar2(40)), 
         ...
```

Comment: This will produce a `FormatException`, not `Overflow`

Comment: Tried it with `Convert.ToSingle(reader.GetValue(), new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"))` but still get an exception `System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.DecimalConv.GetDecimal(IntPtr numCtx) at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i) `

Comment: Seems that the problem is somewhere in the `Oracle.DataAccess.Types.DecimalConv.GetDecimal`;
try convert value to string in the SQL: `select ... cast (LAUFZEIT as VarChar2(100)) ...`